# PHP echoing HTML with CSS class causing an error?

Tags: php

Apologies if this is a very frequently asked question in here but this is really throwing me off as I can't seem to find where my syntax error is:

```
<?php require "../connect.php";

$sql = "SELECT pro_exp_date, pro_exp_descr FROM pro_exp";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) :
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) :
        echo "<dt class='col-md-3'>" . $row["pro_exp_date"] . "</dt><dd class='col-md-9'><p>" . $row["pro_exp_descr"] . "</p></dd>";
    else :
        echo "0 results.";

...
```

The error seems to begin in line `echo "<dt...`, and this is at the start of the page, before there is no semicolons missing or anything like that. Another user in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932914/unexpected-else) suggests to use non-bracketed syntax for easier coding, so I did just that. I have changed `'` to `"` and vice versa in and out of the HTML, nothing works.

ADD: I added `endwhile` and `endif` and that seems to work, no errors — but I tried reverting back to normal bracket syntax and it threw the error again. I even retraced and rewrote the brackets one by one to make sure everything fits, but that doesn't seem to work. `endwhile` and `endif` works just fine.

ADD 2:

This works fine:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) :
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) :
        echo "<dt class='col-md-3'>" . $row["pro_exp_date"] . "</dt><dd class='col-md-9'><p>" . $row["pro_exp_descr"] . "</p></dd>";
    endwhile;
else :
        echo "0 results.";
endif;
```

This doesn't:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<dt class='col-md-3'>" . $row["pro_exp_date"] . "</dt><dd class='col-md-9'><p>" . $row["pro_exp_descr"] . "</p></dd>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results.";
}
```

I don't know why. But the `endif` and `endwhile` works okay.

Comment: where is the while closing?

Comment: Unless you're using PHP like a template language, I wouldn't recommend the alt syntax. Just use braces, ie `while(...) { ... }`

Comment: Before I tried the alt syntax, the closing } bracket was exactly before the ```else``` — this is really throwing me off, but I'll try ending the alt syntax first

Comment: If you're using alt syntax, you must have an `endwhile` and `endif`

Comment: isn't using that syntax harder to use, at the very least most text editors honor `{}` and even highlights the opening and closing, easier on the eyes

Comment: @Kevin that depends. Personally, I've found getting PHP to `echo` great chunks of mostly static HTML is unnecessary and bound to run into issues with string quotes

Comment: _"I tried reverting back to normal bracket syntax and it threw the error again"_  if you want to get to the bottom of this, please show what you tried and show exactly what the error message says

Comment: @Phil - updated again. The error is an unexpected else right at the `while`'s closing bracket.

Comment: You haven't close the `if` block. The syntax for `if..else` is `if { ... } else { ... }` where the `else` comes after the `if` block, not within it

Comment: @Phil ah yes, that's the solution. Hope this thread can help other rookies like me, really basic mistake. Solved then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your `while` and `if` statements:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) :
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) :
        echo "<dt class='col-md-3'>" . $row["pro_exp_date"] . "</dt><dd class='col-md-9'><p>" . $row["pro_exp_descr"] . "</p></dd>";
    endwhile;
else :
    echo "0 results.";
endif;
```

My suggestion is to revert back to brackets (`{` and `}`).

Comment: Oh my God, I'm so sorry for cluttering. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem. Please upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: Wait a minute, if ```endwhile``` is equivalent to ```}```, then I've tried that, it didn't work too.

Comment: @Phil right, added the addendum. I don't know why the brackets don't work, but I ended up using the alt syntax with the `endif` and `endwhile`

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use [alternative syntax for control structures](https://www.php.net/manual/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), it fits best when used as a sort of template language.

For example

```php
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) :
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>
        <dt class="col-md-3"><?= htmlspecialchars($row['pro_exp_date']) ?></dt>
        <dd class="col-md-9">
            <p><?= htmlspecialchars($row['pro_exp_descr']) ?></p>
        </dd>
    <?php endwhile; 
else : ?>
    0 results
<?php endif ?>
```